# Input quick text inside status bar

Tags: applications, notification-bar

There are apps that display buttons in the notifications for a quick feedback.

What I need is a way a that a text input in a file stays in the background and displays inside the status bar/notifications   (input text that is  40 characters would suffice). I do NOT mean a notes app for displaying notes.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Just give me a hint if I need to write it myself.

Comment: Since app recommendations are off topic, reworded your question. If that is not OK by you, please roll back the edit

Answer (score 2):

There is an app [Notin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nisahnt.nishantbafna.notifydemo) which was amongst the top apps of the year as per XDA and by a coincidence had downloaded today  and works well

> With notin, never forget the little things anymore. It's an easy way to save notes or reminders as a notification.
>
> notin helps you in reminding things you need to do, random numbers you do not want to save in your contacts and many more through the help of Notifications. The reminder doesn't pop-up or rings, it just sits there and still does it's job most efficiently.

Comment: That is half of what I need, no more need to switch apps. But I can't do anything with the notes, they just sit in the bar. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: The best would be to save the lines in a file. But I'll like your answer, as the app already is useful for me.